# Perform Action on Each Record from SQLDataSource

Tags: vb.net, loops, sqldatasource

I've submitted a bunch of questions as of late - but this has been a great repository of information. I'm a .NET nub, as you can see, so if I'm missing basics or information please let me know and I'll try and fill in the gaps.

I'm using ASP.NET/VB.NET to create this with SQL 2005.  I have a project where I'd like to take a set of records from a table, then send each one through an API, get a result and writeback the result to a table, then move to the next.

Initially, my thought was create a SQLDataSource that grabs all the records, then perform the action on a button to do the action of sending through each record.

Is there a way I can call the recordset from SQLDataSource and perform a loop?  I'm thinking something like in Classic ASP/VBScript where you would open a RecordSet, do an action, then Loop until the RS was EoF.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can may want to put your results in a dataset. After getting the results, you can loop through the returned rows

```
Dim ds As Dataset = GetSomeDataFromSq

For Each dr As DataRow In ds.Tables(0).Rows
    Console.WriteLine (dr("ColName"))
Next
```

You could also use a sqlDataReader

```
    Using conn As sqlconnection = New sqlconnection("put conn info")
        Using MyCommand As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand("SELECT ProductName FROM products", conn)
            conn.Open()
            Using myDataREader As SqlDataReader = MyCommand.ExecuteReader
                While myDataREader.Read
                    Response.Write("Name: " & myDataREader.Item("ProductName"))
                End While
            End Using
        End Using
    End Using
```

Comment: I'm able to use the SqlDataReader - but there is no way to utilize the SqlDataSource control in the same fashion?

Comment: After getting things and using the same method to insert to a table - this worked perfect.  Thanks Lareau!